# In share kit is there any way to share multiple items like image, text, url at a time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, ipad

I want share an image, text, url at a time and i am using share kit.
But here it is sharing only one item at a time.
is there any way to share multiple items like image, text, url at a time.

Plz help me out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation here: http://getsharekit.com/docs/

I noticed that it appears as though you can only share one item at a time, which is why they put each type of sharing under a different heading and there is no combination heading.
[image: sharekit]

Why not just create a custom method that implements all these various callbacks into one? Such as creating an array of items and sharing them all at once.

```
- (void)myButtonHandlerAction
{
    // Create an array of items here url, date, etc.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://getsharekit.com"];
    SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"ShareKit is Awesome!"];

    // Get the ShareKit action sheet
    SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];

    / Display the action sheet
    [actionSheet showFromToolbar:navigationController.toolbar];
}
```